# What are the fastest ways to lose weight?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, health

I am 35, I mesure 184cm and my weight is around 100kg. Do you have any ideas on how I could lose weight ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have a look on thequestions of this site of the same  manner? I think this sis a duplicate question, please have a look here : https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=lose+weight

Comment: Ebola or some other hemorrhagic fever, if health is not a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Good decision, I wish you best of luck during your weight loss period. But remember 1 thing never give up!

Here are six simple weight loss tips you can use today:

**Number 1:** STOP drinking beer (or any alcohol), drinking one single beer is equivalent to 7 slices of bread.

**Number 2:** Allow yourself a cheat meal once a week. I know you might think why should I do that? It will do the opposite of losing weight! Well, yes that’s true, but remember you are not a ROBOT. Having a cheat meal once a week will keep you motivated and therefore you won’t think losing weight is too hard and finish by quitting everything.

**Number 3:** Don’t eat the same food every day. Many people eat chicken and rice all the time because there is a low percentage of fat. But after a week or two, you will get bored. Go on some cooking website and try simple and healthy recipes.

**Number 4:** Go to the supermarket after eating. I know it’s weird, but its effective. Once you are full your body won’t desire any more calories and therefore you won’t buy any junk food.

**Number 5:** Buy smaller plates. This again, is another wired trick, but there are over 50 studies to support my tip. Having smaller plates will reduce the quantity of food you can put on it and your brain will think its full.

**Number 6:** If you are still hungry after your meal, eat either bananas or apples. These two fruits will help you full your stomach with a very low calorie count. And if you are still hungry after that drink water or green tea.

If you want more information on how to lose weight here is a website I quite like : [tip4fitness.com](https://tip4fitness.com)

Comment: 2. Doesn't work for everyone, for some people with impulse control issues, a cheat meal can be a really bad idea. 3. Actually, eating the same thing every day is a good way to lose weight as you don't have to think about meal planning once you've got meals that fit your caloric needs, you just have to be careful about lack of nutrients / vitamins / minerals in the diet.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't drink alcohol.
- Don't eat a lot of sugar.
- Eat lots of salads and fruits.
- Go to the gym and workout for 30 minutes to 2 hours (depends on fast you want to lose weight or how much you want to lose)
- Don't workout for too long or you'll get hungry and eat junk food or such.
- Don't consume lots of carbs.

Comment: Your answer is pretty specific.  Are you claiming that your approach will work for anyone?